# Save _stprintf_s in a txt file

Tags: c++, printing, save

I am new to C++ and I have a pre-built code that needs to be modified to save its printing output. In the original code, it contains lines such as

```
_stprintf_s(szFrame, _countof(szFrame), _T("%+011.6f %+011.6f %+011.6f   "), pData[0], pData[1], pData[2]));
```

and

```
_stprintf_s(szFrame, _countof(szFrame), _T("%4x Sensor %d:  "), pHdr->preamble, pHdr->station );
```

such type of _stprintf_s prints out some results on the command prompt while running. My goal is to save them as a text file. However, when I tried to save this following the code below, it does not save the exact strings. Instead it saves a number (around 6 digits). My problem is about _T(" ") part with 3 data of pData[0], pData[1], pData[2]. Each one is supposed to have a number with a format of %+011.6f. But I only get one number like 164242 when I run the code below. Maybe it is just getting the first part "szFrame".

```
#include<fstream>
ofstream myfile("C:/Users/slee23/Desktop/newfolder/example.txt", ios_base::app); 
myfile << _stprintf_s(szFrame, _countof(szFrame), _T("%+011.6f %+011.6f %+011.6f   "), pData[0], pData[1], pData[2]));
```

or

```
myfile << std::to_string(_stprintf_s(szFrame, _countof(szFrame), _T("%+011.6f %+011.6f %+011.6f   "), pData[0], pData[1], pData[2])));
```

Could you give me any recommendation to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing code is printing into the buffer szFrame, you need to write that to the stream.

```
#include<fstream>

_stprintf_s(szFrame, _countof(szFrame), _T("%+011.6f %+011.6f %+011.6f   "), pData[0], pData[1], pData[2]);

ofstream myfile("C:/Users/slee23/Desktop/newfolder/example.txt", ios_base::app); 
myFile << szFrame;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! The szFrame can be printed out in that way. My problem is about _T("    ") part with 3 data of pData[0], pData[1], pData[2]. Each one is supposed to have a number with a format of %+011.6f. But I only get one number like 164242.

Comment: I got it!! I deleted myfile << _stprintf_s line. and just printed myFile <<szFrame; szFrmae had all the information that I wanted!